# Unable To Create Table, Unsure of what to do (Error: 150)

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am creating several tables at once and I keep getting the error(150):

> #1005 - Can't create table 'waget.tour' (errno: 150)

and despite me knowing what the error is, I simply can't fix it. All tables references in the table "tour" are all there and exist, with keys where Foreign keys are referenced. I've checked it over plenty of times, and simply can't find anything. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

(Getting error when creating the table "tours")

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tourPayment(
    tourPaymentNumber int,
    tourCost int(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (tourPaymentNumber),
    KEY (tourCost)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel(
    hotelID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hotelName varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (hotelID),
    KEY (hotelName)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salutation(
    salutationID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    salutation varchar(4),
    KEY (salutation)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer(
    custID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    custSalutation varchar(4),
    custLname varchar(30),
    custAdd varchar(100),
    custPcode varchar(4),
    custState varChar(20),
    custPhone varchar(10),
    custHotel varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (custID),
    FOREIGN KEY (custHotel) REFERENCES hotel(hotelName),
    FOREIGN KEY (custSalutation) REFERENCES salutation(salutation)
);

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus(
    busID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    busMake varchar(30),
    busSeats varchar(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (busID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS busDriver(
    driverID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    driverName varchar(20),
    driverEmail varchar(40),
    busID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (driverID),
    FOREIGN KEY (busID) REFERENCES bus(busID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tour(
    DailyTourID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NoOfPeople int(3),
    tourDate DATE,
    tourTime TIME,
    tourName varchar(30),
    tourCost int(7),
    tourDriverID varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (DailyTourID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tourDriverID) REFERENCES busDriver(driverID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tourCost) REFERENCES tourPayment(tourCost)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TourCustLink(
    TourCustLinkID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TourID int,
    custID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (TourCustLinkID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TourID) REFERENCES tour(DailyTourID),
    FOREIGN KEY (custID) REFERENCES customer(custID)
);
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (tourDriverID) REFERENCES busDriver(driverID)` - `tourDriverID` is a `varchar(20)` and `driverID` is an `int`. That might be causing the issue.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie tourDriverID varchar(20) is define VARCHAR in tour but busDriver.driverID is INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
FOREIGN KEY (tourDriverID) REFERENCES busDriver(driverID)
```

references an INT but is declared as varchar(20)

Comment: i think the 2nd point is incorrect. the 1st is a damn good point.

Comment: Thankyou. Sometime I go through things and completely miss it :c. Good to have other people check.

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT fields all need to be PRIMARY KEY's, so try changing salutation to be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salutation(
    salutationID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    salutation varchar(4),
    PRIMARY KEY (salutationID),
    KEY (salutation)
);
```

Additionally in tour you have the wrong datatype for tourDriverID, it should be INT to match the referenced key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tour(
    DailyTourID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NoOfPeople int(3),
    tourDate DATE,
    tourTime TIME,
    tourName varchar(30),
    tourCost int(7),
    tourDriverID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (DailyTourID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tourDriverID) REFERENCES busDriver(driverID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tourCost) REFERENCES tourPayment(tourCost)
);
```

SQL fiddle example in full can be found here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/840b9

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's easy to try and create tables one by one and you would get a better error message..
Your Problem is the table `salutation` since you have to define the AUTO_INCREMENT field (in your case `salutationID) as KEY and not the field`salutation`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salutation(
   salutationID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
   salutation varchar(4),
   KEY (salutationID) -- here is your error
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code you ran? if so, the error is about the AUTO_INCREMENT needing to be a Key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salutation(
    salutationID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    salutation varchar(4),
    KEY (salutation)
);
```

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salutation(
    salutationID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    salutation varchar(4),
    KEY (salutationID)
);
```

and make other a FOREIGN KEY if you need to.

Cheers.